# AD user with group write rights opens read only files

Tags: network-shares, active-directory, windows-domain

I don't know whats preventing a windows domain user from writing into network share files, and I'd thought to ask for help.

The user should get modify/write rights to any file on the network share through membership to a group that has write/modify rights (all but the full rights). The audit tab in security says "success" for the user to have modify rights. By my count the user should be able to create and modify files. I don't know which right overrides this.

They can open for eg. Excel files, but they will open in Read Only state.

After doing modifications to the folder rights the user logged in and out, thinking this will refresh something.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

When working with Active Directory, the following needs to be understood:
When a user is given permission through access groups, the membership of these groups is cached during logon.

Any changes made in Active Directory, will not be loaded until the user logs off and logs on again.

Network folders will give access if the local cached security settings grand permission using AD security groups.

Note1: Adding a user to the network folder security will be instant, but managing that is going to be a pain.
Note2: if the user is already a member of the AD group, since their login, adding that membergroup to the network folder will also be instant.

If the user has sufficient permissions to read, the file will be accessible. For modifying a file, 2 permissions are required: Write and Modify. One is required to add/remove data to the file, the other is required to change flags that tell the file that it was modified, such as modify date.

If neither both are set, but one is, the user will still get read only rights.

If the user has write rights, the program will then attempt to open the file with write access. If the program fails, it either gives an error, or falls back to read-only access.

Not getting write access on a file if the permissions are set correctly can happen under the following conditions:

- The file is marked as opened by someone else from the FileServer on a network share (this can be verified through Computer Management, Shared Folders, Open Files and see if the file is listed there. This will also tell you who uses it and the lock can be removed there if necessary.)
- Someone actually has the file open, and as such there's a write lock on the file (this is similar to the above, except this happens everywhere, not just network shares on a file server)
- You have the file open yourself but you are unaware (for example, having preview pane enabled in Windows Explorer will open the file to read and sometimes creates a lock.
- The file is locked in a weird way and no one can actually write to the file. Sometimes renaming the file works and then it works until you rename it back. Often, restarting the file server fixes the issue permanently.
- The problem is limited to office files. A valid license is required to edit files.